# Android GPS not recover after signal loss

Tags: android, gps, location, fusedlocationproviderclient

The problem is that after GPS signal is lost in subway, tunnels and so on, FusedLocation provider is not getting locations when phone is coming back to open air. Is there a way to force GPS refresh locations periodically?
Also I notice that when the mobile device stay still it periodically receives bunches of locations having identical coordinates, why does so happens? It is not likely that GPS signal has totally identical longitude and latitude for some time. Probably it happens because FLP switches to WiFi or mobile coordinates source when the device is not moving? I can't catch any documentation regarding these issues, sorry.